# How I can run this script in node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, error-handling

I have install all modules need to run this script using CMD. When I am run this script in node.js through webmatrix:

```
var http = require('http');
var everyauth = require('everyauth');
var app = require('express').createServer();

app.get('/', function(request, response) {
    response.send('Hello Express!!');
});

app.listen(2455);
```

It's not working. The error is:

```
iisnode encountered an error when processing the request.

HRESULT: 0x2
HTTP status: 500
HTTP reason: Internal Server Error
You are receiving this HTTP 200 response because system.webServer/iisnode/@devErrorsEnabled configuration setting is 'true'.

In addition to the log of stdout and stderr of the node.exe process, consider using debugging and ETW traces to further diagnose the problem.

The node.exe process has not written any information to the stdout or stderr.
```

I have tried with different different script from blog but they do not work. I tried Steven Sanderson's template in webmatrix and that does work.

Comment: Well... did you try `app` instead of `application`? That's what the error says.

Comment: Also it's easier to use examples from http://expressjs.com/guide.html.

Comment: you dont need the modules http and everyauth try to comment these out.

Comment: @jurka, I have tried but same error again.

Comment: Well when you start the application with node app.js then the server starts listening for connections and when you hit the page on browser it throws the error ? Seems like your using windows ? Try to change the port.

Answer (score 2):

To use your application with iisnode, you have to use port/socket supplied by iisnode (as in this case you're using IIS as a webserver instead of the one bundled in node).

Replace the last line with `app.listen(process.env.port || 2455);`, so that it will both work well with iisnode and be available on port 2455 when run with `node.exe app.js`.

Answer (score 1):

Use

> app.listen(process.env.port || 2455);

instead of `

> app.listen(portno);

cause it's iisnode web server.